# Why covariant quantization is not enough for a relativistic quantum mechanics theory?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-field-theory, special-relativity, second-quantization, klein-gordon-equation

It is often said in quantum field theory books that a quantum theory of fields is needed because every other attempt to develop a quantum-mechanical theory compatible with the principles of relativity was flawed. The prototype example is the attempt of obtaining a Schrödinger equation describing a relativistic particle, which led to the Klein-Gordon equation. Since the energy of such a particle would satisfy $E^{2} = p^{2}+m^{2}$, it is natural to assume that a suitable Hamiltonian operator would be given by:
$$H = \frac{\partial^{2}}{\partial t^{2}} -\nabla^{2} + m^{2} \tag{1}\label{1}$$
The problem with this approach is that the associated Schrödinger equation allows for negative energy eigenvalues, which is not physically acceptable.

There is another way to approach the quantization of a single relativistic particle, which I believe is known as the *covariant quantization*. The postulates of quantum mechanics tell us that every quantum system is associated to a Hilbert space $\mathscr{H}$ and unit vectors (actually, rays) of this space represent quantum states. Given a state $\psi_{0}$ at time $t=0$, the state of the system at time $t>0$ is then given by $\psi_{t} := e^{-itH}\psi_{0}$. The time evolution postulate makes it clear that position and time are not in equal footing, and we would need to modify this postulate to be able develop a relativistic theory.

An appropriate new postulate is the following. Any quantum system comes equipped with a strongly continuous representation of the (restricted) Poincaré group $\mathcal{P}$ on $\mathscr{H}$. Under this hypothesis, the state space of a single relativistic particle is then $L^{2}(X_{m},d\lambda_{m})$, where $X_{m}$ is the mass hyperboloid:
$$X_{m} := \{p \in \mathbb{R}^{1+3}: |p|^{2} = m^{2}, p_{0} \ge 0\},$$
and $\lambda_{m}$ is the unique invariant measure on $X_{m}$, called the Lorentz measure. A (actually irreducible) representation $U$ of $\mathcal{P}$ on $L^{2}(X_{m},d\lambda_{m})$ is given by:
$$U(a,\Lambda) := e^{i\langle a,p\rangle}\psi(\Lambda^{-1}p).$$
We can pass everything to position space with a suitable definition of Fourier transform.

This scheme is usually discussed in quantum field theory books. From a mathematical point of view, a quantum field theory is defined by the Gårding–Wightman axioms and these spaces of single (and also many) relativistic particles are included in the set of possible states.

Here is what I don't understand. Isn't this approach successfully developing the relativistic quantum theory one wanted in the first place? In other words, why do we still need a quantum theory of *fields* if this scheme seems to account for the description of relativistic particles?

Comment: I'm not really sure what this question is looking for. You've presented the theory of a single relativistic particle. Quantum field theory describes the theory of an indeterminate number of relativistic particles that interact. See Weinberg's QFT book if you want to see QFT stringently motivated along the lines of the particle picture.

Comment: Without wanting to sound trite by repeating this again: quantum mechanics is not a theory of particles. It's a theory of energy exchange. What everybody calls "a particle" is only the asymptotic initial/final state at infinity. Nowhere else does the notion of a well defined state of countable quanta exist. The "state" during the interaction (where the beams in an accelerator collide) is a superposition of an infinite number of possible field modes.

Comment: Thank you for the comments! I don't know if this is true, but the message I get from why a quantum theory of *fields* was developed is that the attempts of developing a relativistic quantum theory by means of wave mechanics etc was not successful. In other words, qft was not developed to be a theory of an indeterminate number of particles, but destiny led to such a theory where one considers an indeterminate number of fields which create and destroy particles.

Comment: Again, not sure if this is true. But it is the message I got by reading the intro of some qft books. But then, the concepts discussed in the post seem to actually be successful in this program. Maybe I was just getting the wrong message after all?

Comment: *one considers an indeterminate number of fields* No. As an example, the Standard Model has only a small, finite number of fields. All electrons and positrons are quanta of a single field.